# How to create an Origin-Destination matrix in R for multiple observations tied to unique ID?

Tags: r, od

Here I have a sample dataset and my goal is to generate matrices (explained below)

```r
ID <- c(1,1,1,
        2,2,
        3,3,3,3,3,3,
        4,4,4,
        5,5,5,5,5,5)
OZ <- c("OZ1", "OZ1", "OZ3", 
        "OZ3", "OZ3", 
        "OZ1", "OZ3", "OZ1", "OZ3", "OZ1", "OZ3", 
        "OZ1", "OZ2", "OZ3",
        "OZ2", "OZ3", "OZ2", "OZ1", "OZ3", "OZ2")
DZ <- c("DZ3", "DZ3", "DZ1", 
        "DZ1", "DZ2",
        "DZ3", "DZ1", "DZ3", "DZ1", "DZ3", "DZ1",
        "DZ3", "DZ3", "DZ1",
        "DZ3", "DZ2", "DZ3", "DZ3", "DZ1", "DZ3")
        
OD <- data. Frame(ID, OZ, DZ)
```

What I am looking to do is to generate two sets of matrices, one for each `ID` and the other for all `ID`.

**For the first case**, I am looking for something like this:

```
#For ID = 1
       OZ1  OZ2  OZ3
  DZ1   0    0    1
  DZ2   0    0    0
  DZ3   2    0    0
```

And I need to do this for about 500 unique `ID`s for about 4000 observations. My best educated guess is to use a loop function within which I write the function to generate this matrix.

**The second part** is to get another matrix that should look like below:

```
ID  OZ1DZ1  OZ1DZ2  OZ1DZ3  OZ2DZ1  OZ2DZ2  OZ2DZ3  OZ3DZ1  OZ3DZ2  OZ3DZ3
1     0       0        2      0        0       0       1       0      0
2     0       0        0      0        0       0       1       1      0
3     0       0        1      0        0       0       1       0      0
4     0       0        1      0        0       1       1       0      0
5     0       0        1      0        0       3       1       1      0
```

In my attempt to solve this, I looked at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/od/vignettes/od.html and tried `OD_matrix <- od_to_odmatrix(OD)` which did not give me any count (presumably because `OZ` and `DZ` are characters). I looked at various other questions on this forum, but none seem to work for my case.  
Hence, as always, your time and help are really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first part:

```
 table(rev(OD))
, , ID = 1

     OZ
DZ    OZ1 OZ2 OZ3
  DZ1   0   0   1
  DZ2   0   0   0
  DZ3   2   0   0

, , ID = 2

     OZ
DZ    OZ1 OZ2 OZ3
  DZ1   0   0   1
  DZ2   0   0   1
  DZ3   0   0   0

, , ID = 3

     OZ
DZ    OZ1 OZ2 OZ3
  DZ1   0   0   3
  DZ2   0   0   0
  DZ3   3   0   0

, , ID = 4

     OZ
DZ    OZ1 OZ2 OZ3
  DZ1   0   0   1
  DZ2   0   0   0
  DZ3   1   1   0

, , ID = 5

     OZ
DZ    OZ1 OZ2 OZ3
  DZ1   0   0   1
  DZ2   0   0   1
  DZ3   1   3   0
```

If you need the results in a list format, you should do `asplit(table(rev(OD)),3)`

The second:

```
 with(OD, table(ID, interaction(OZ, DZ, sep = "", lex.order = TRUE)))
   
ID  OZ1DZ1 OZ1DZ2 OZ1DZ3 OZ2DZ1 OZ2DZ2 OZ2DZ3 OZ3DZ1 OZ3DZ2 OZ3DZ3
  1      0      0      2      0      0      0      1      0      0
  2      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0
  3      0      0      3      0      0      0      3      0      0
  4      0      0      1      0      0      1      1      0      0
  5      0      0      1      0      0      3      1      1      0
```

Comment: Simpler part 2 - `with(OD, table(ID, interaction(OZ, DZ, sep = "", lex.order = TRUE)))`.